# gwt using static variables in css

Tags: css, gwt, variables, static, constants

css:

```
@eval ctHeaderC1 com.CssServlet.ctHeaderColor1;
@eval ctHeaderC2 com.CssServlet.ctHeaderColor2;

.cellTableHeader {
    background: ctHeaderC1;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, ctHeaderC1 0%, ctHeaderC2 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, ctHeaderC1 ), color-stop(100%, ctHeaderC2 ));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, ctHeaderC1 0%, ctHeaderC2 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, ctHeaderC1 0%, ctHeaderC2 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, ctHeaderC1 0%, ctHeaderC2 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, ctHeaderC1 0%, ctHeaderC2 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='ctHeaderC1', endColorstr='ctHeaderC2',GradientType=0 );          
}
```

i wont to replace all variables

but only "background: ctHeaderC1;" was replaced

:(

Comment: Which version of GWT are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in GWT 2.5: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5771

Upgrade! ;-)

Comment: thx but works it with @eval too? because i get the values from a java class?

Comment: I believe it's about substitutions as a whole, wherever the value comes from. Haven't checked though.